# What is the difference between mathematical psychology and quantitative psychology?

Tags: methodology

Upon researching this question I realized that there are many graduate programs in quantitative psychology, but not too many for mathematical psychology. If you know of any universities that offer graduate degrees specializing in mathematical psychology please include it in your answer.

Comment: My guess is they are a different name to refer to the same thing, but I do not know. In regards to your closing question, I recommend you to remove it since it is both (1) a second question (we focus on one question per... question here) and (2) the answer would be long and meaningless. Does an answer constitute a list of all universities which teach this?

Comment: Agreed, and you could also look for 'cognitive psychology', and many of the 'cognitive X' half-breeds (although some of these will surely be abominations to you, it's hard to tell which without a little more context!). If you're looking for potential places to do a grad program, the main thing worth caring about is your potential supervisor. Your working relationship with them and the area of overlap between your interests and theirs determine your grad school experience... the name of the program is not very informative about this.